# Collection of open problems in Partial differential equations

Tags: mathematics, mathematical-physics

Except Navier-Stokes equation, are there any other interesting open problems in partial differential equations?

I want to know the collection of problems, which are easy to understand but difficult to solve. Like in number theory, we have [Goldbach conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) which is easy to understand, but still unsolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a collection of open problems concerning various areas in function theory, functional analysis, theory of linear and nonlinear partial differential equations.
[Seventy Five (Thousand) Unsolved Problems in Analysis and Partial Differential Equations](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00020-018-2460-8)